# How to use an endless adapter inside another adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using a view that supports list inside another list. I want to multi-thread it and also use Endlessadapter with it.

This view, has its own adapter. How do I pass the data, that I get to this adapter to Endless adapter. All are in the same name-space. I don't think so I'm very clear with the question, but I'm also rather confused with my own architecture. I'll shape the question a bit better if I get some help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use:

**Expandable ListView adapter**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html

[Problem with expandable list adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992797/problem-with-expandable-list-adapter)